# Windows 7 Update Pack Download

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

Is there a "Windows 7 Update Pack" that I can download that contains all the Windows Updates?

Since I have a very slow DSL connection at home, I am planning to download it somewhere that has high speed internet access.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't such a product from Microsoft, but there are alternatives.

See this :  [Download Windows 7 Updates Offline with WSUS Offline Update](http://www.blogsdna.com/6333/download-windows-7-updates-offline-with-wsus-offline-update.htm).

> WSUS Offline Update lets you to easily
>   download patches and updates for your
>   Windows and Office without going
>   through the whole procedure on
>   Microsoft’s Windows Update website.
>
> You can also download Windows 7
>   updates on USB drive and carry with
>   you to install on computers not
>   connected to internet.

[image]

**New : SP2 for Windows 7 (and 8.1) has arrived**

Microsoft has published what is actually SP2 for Windows 7 and 8.1.
This update will not be available from Windows Update for some unknown reason.

Read about how to get it in the article :
[Microsoft overhauls Windows 7 and 8.1 updating -- but don't call it a service pack](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3071737/microsoft-windows/microsoft-overhauls-windows-7-and-81-updating-but-dont-call-it-a-service-pack.html?token=%23tk.IFWNLE_nlt_infoworld_tech_microsoft_2016-05-18&idg_eid=daf30e86c221aa1a6e7994afe03ad0d9&utm_source=Sailthru&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=InfoWorld%20Windows%20Report%202016-05-18&utm_term=infoworld_tech_microsoft#tk.IFW_nlt_infoworld_tech_microsoft_2016-05-18).