# How to get fine-grained control over Windows 7 update process?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, windows-update

I am trying to install Windows 7 in VirtualBox, but since it's pretty outdated, it finds like 150 updates and chokes while downloading/installing them. It estimates the download size at 1GB+, svchost.exe and TrustedInstaller.exe show gigabytes of read/write activity and it's been chewing the hard drive for a few days already. The VM has 4GB of RAM and task manager never shows that all of it is used, so I suppose disk activity isn't related to swapping.

Question: how do I get fine-grained control over update process? I don't want to click a button and know nothing about what's happening under the curtain. I suppose that when Windows finds updates, it builds an ordered list of them (or a list consisting of groups of updates that must be installed together). I want to see that list and I need a way to cherry-pick each of them and install them manually. Is it possible? How?

Comment: Run windows updates from the control panel, all available updates will be shown there, also change your updates setting to anything but automatically install updates.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to your question, but when I spin up new test VMs for Windows 7, I download the Convenience Rollup from the Microsoft Update Catalog.  It's KB3125574 , about 50 megabytes. That way, I get stuck less in the low-feedback Windows Update control panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 7 SP1 Windows Update stuck checking for updates](https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/98712/windows-7-update-pack-download/98715#98715)

Comment: If that explanation isn't good enough we can close this as a duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/7261/offline-update-of-windows/115782#115782) question.

Comment: @Ramhound it is related but not a duplicate. I have provided details about Windows Update for context. Definitely want to learn a way of manual update management, like installing them one by one, by hand, perhaps in the order that Microsoft releases them.

Comment: You are asking for a way to view a list of updates, and selectively download updates, applicable to  your machine.  WSUS Offline would do that.  So I disagree that it's not a duplicate.